# How I can implement f-string in C++ like in Python?

Tags: c++

I want to create an F string for C++, as in Python. But I don’t understand how the expression in curly braces {} is parsed.

Example (Python):

```
world = "world"
print(f "Hello {world}")
```

How do I do the same, but in C++?

```
std::string world = "world!"
std::cout << f("Hello {world}") << std::endl;
```

Output

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: I would say that is impossible in C++, because it requires compiled C++ code to have knowledge of the names of C++ variables. That doesn't happen in C++.

Comment: Exactly like this example, is currently not possible in C++

Comment: You won't be able to do that. You can't look up a variable by it's name using a string in c++. It's a completely statically typed language with little to no reflection.

Comment: @super I wouldn't say "You won't be able". Reflection is coming to C++.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I would say that splitting hairs is fairly pointless.

Comment: From https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/doc/format.html, the example is `cout << boost::format("writing %1%,  x=%2% : %3%-th try") % "toto" % 40.23 % 50;` which is probably as close as you can get to what you want.

Comment: Or maybe there exists precompiler out there (or you write your own) that replaces such commands with the appropriate C++ code, such that your example would be precompiled to `std::cout << "Hello " << world << std::endl;`

Comment: @super I doing understand what "splitting hairs" means? Last year the C++ comitee accepted the technical specifiction for Reflection. (In theory this could be implemented NOW by any compiler) This is one of the major goals for C++23. Maybe this comment will be read a few years from today, then it will be misleading.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Getting pedantic. We can only speculate on what C++ may or may not do in the future. Today it does not offer reflection. This cannot be implemented as-is. A C++ function cannot discover what variables were set in the caller scope and behave differently.

Comment: It looks like [F Strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) are a language syntax feature, so until C++ has such a thing it's not possible.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk It's not going to be possible with current reflexion TS either it seems.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Google says *Splitting hairs - make small and overfine distinctions*. **If** someone happens to read this several years from now **and** also misinterprets what I said **and** does not check on the date of posting **and** so on... it **might** incovenience someone a little bit. Hardly seems discussion worthy.

Comment: You can do this with a slightly different syntax: `std::cout << "Hello " << world << std::endl;` It's a bit too verbose and annoying but it works. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Once a program is compiled (and debug mode is not used), the name of the variables is lost. So even if you parsed the f-string, you would have no direct way to identify the expected variables.

But it is a real use case that is addressed by *pre-compilers*: you use special declarations that either depend on macros to save the name of the variables that would be allowed in f-strings, or use a pre-compiler phase that translate a special code into C++ code + do the required special processing (here save the name of the variable in a map). Examples of using macros can be found in Microsoft MFC, and example of pre-compilers can be found in [qt](https://qt.io) or Oracle pro*C.

I am afraid that it will be more complex to develop than the gain for the programmer so my answer boils down to *it could be possible, but IMHO is not worth it*.

Answer (score 0):

As Serge Ballista and others have already written, it is (currently) not possible in C++ for `cout` to resolve the name of a variable to insert its contents. Nevertheless it is possible to use a format string with the number/ position of an argument. With these you can pass the according variables as arguments and refer to them with the number of their position. C++20 defines [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) in the `<format>` standard library. If you are using an older compiler version, you could use the [Boost Format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) library as in this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string a("world");
    std::string b("Hello");

    std::cout << boost::format("%2% %1%!\n") % a % b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As many comments points out, there is no such facility for string interpolation.
However, if you are trying to make a string with some variable output, you may use sprintf to mimic the string interpolation.

Update : Now this comment is not valid. C++20 now supports the string interpolation as another answer pointed out.