# Is it possible to format strings in C++ like python's f-strings?

Tags: python, c++, f-string

In Python it's possible to format strings conveniently using f-strings:

```py
a = 42
print(f"a = {a}") # prints "a = 42"
```

Is it possible to do something like this in C++ at compile time, or is `format("a = {}", a);` the closest thing to f-strings?

EDIT: I'm not saying that that these formatting methods should work at runtime. Can't compiler just look up variable visible in current scope by it's name at compile time? Like, if it encounters string `f"foo = {foo}"` it could just substitute this string to `std::format("foo = {}", foo)` in code

Comment: C++ doesn't have the reflection capabilities to make this possible. Once compiled the `a` variable is gone, it is, at best, a value. In many cases it goes away entirely.

Comment: I upvoted the question because it would be so lovely, but C++ is unlikely to get that.  So far the least-unhappy I get with C++ output formatting is with the fmt library: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

Comment: as an aside, `print(f"{a = }"` is a recent Python shortcut for `print(f"a = {a}")`

Answer (score 14):

C++ doesn't have reflection. As a result, it is impossible to offer a reference to a variable by its name.

But as @NicolBolas points out, even *if* reflection was present, there would be more needed. Not only would it require huge language support (telling the called function what the variables were in the calling scope), it would also prevent tons of optimization. The compiler could not remove any variable, as the format string (when not known at compile time) could end up referring to any variable in-scope.

So, no. `std::format` is the closest.

Comment: Reflection would only be the *beginning* of what is needed to make this work.

Comment: yeah, good point. I'll try to make the answer clearer.

Comment: I'm not saying that that these formatting methods should work at runtime. Can't compiler just look up variable visible in current scope by it's name at compile time? Like, if it encounters string `f"foo = {foo}"` it could just substitute this string to `std::format("foo = {}", foo)` in code

Comment: We had so much ~fun~ pain with preprocessor in C++, there's no way such substitution would be approved by the committee (well, I hope)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why Bamberghh's suggestion is not a trivial solution for this to be available in compile-time. The two syntaxes are equivalent in a 1:1 relationship, aren't they? If they are, I don't see the complication. Please explain. Why can't this just be syntactic-sugar for `std::format`?

Comment: @Gulzar: It can't be because C++ doesn't work that way. You would have to change the *language* to make that happen. There is no way to convert text into a C++ identifier. And even if you could do so, there's no way for one function to reach out into the scope of its caller and access variables there.

Comment: @NicolBolas In `f"foo = {foo}"`, the second `foo` could be understood at compile time as a token, rather than as text. Maybe with slightly different syntax, but surely it is possible. I don't understand why the second `foo` should be refered to as text, rather than as a variable, just like it is with `std::format("foo = {}", foo)`?

Answer (score 5):

C++ has no f-string mechanism. [String interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62443669/734069) is not possible in the language as it stands. Even with compile-time function calls, you would also need to have such a function "reach out" into the caller's scope to retrieve the contents of those variables and format them appropriately. That would mean that the behavior of a function-based string interpolation mechanism would have to be different, not just based on what string it takes, but based on where it gets called.

That's not a thing C++ really allows.

Comment: Why is this different from the `std::format("foo = {}", foo)` case?

Comment: @Gulzar: Because the *compiler* isn't reaching out of the string, finding a variable named "foo", and inserting it into the command. If you want to pass in `foo`, then `foo` has to explicitly be one of the variables in the function call. That function call works like any other C++ function call; no compiler magic is needed.

Comment: The magic I want is to write `printf(f"foo={foo}")` and for the compiler to understand it as `printf(std::format("foo = {}", foo))`. Is this doable? Is it bad? If it is bad, please explain why?

Comment: @Gulzar: I know what you want. But it would require changes to the language. It cannot be done in C++ as it stands. And the OP was asking specifically about what could be done in C++ to make it work, not whether a language change could make it work.

Answer (score 5):

There's no good way do that.

With some heavy macros you could achieve syntax like `F(a = ARG(a))` (where `F` and `ARG` are macros), and it will *kind of* work, but with major limitations (see below).

Here's an example implementation relying on libfmt:

```
#define F(...) F_LOW( (str, __VA_ARGS__ ) )
#define ARG(...) )(expr, __VA_ARGS__ )(str,

#define F_LOW(...) ::fmt::format(F_END(F_STR_LOOP_A __VA_ARGS__) F_END(F_ARG_LOOP_A __VA_ARGS__))

#define F_END(...) F_END_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define F_END_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_END

#define F_CAT(a, b) F_CAT_(a, b)
#define F_CAT_(a, b) a##b

#define F_STR_LOOP_A(...) F_STR_LOOP_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) F_STR_LOOP_B
#define F_STR_LOOP_B(...) F_STR_LOOP_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) F_STR_LOOP_A
#define F_STR_LOOP_A_END
#define F_STR_LOOP_B_END
#define F_STR_LOOP_BODY(tag, ...) F_CAT(F_STR_LOOP_BODY_, tag)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define F_STR_LOOP_BODY_str(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define F_STR_LOOP_BODY_expr(...) "{}"

#define F_ARG_LOOP_A(...) F_ARG_LOOP_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) F_ARG_LOOP_B
#define F_ARG_LOOP_B(...) F_ARG_LOOP_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) F_ARG_LOOP_A
#define F_ARG_LOOP_A_END
#define F_ARG_LOOP_B_END
#define F_ARG_LOOP_BODY(tag, ...) F_CAT(F_ARG_LOOP_BODY_, tag)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define F_ARG_LOOP_BODY_str(...)
#define F_ARG_LOOP_BODY_expr(...) , __VA_ARGS__
```

For example, with those macros `F(a=ARG(a), b=ARG(b))` will be equivalent to pythonic `f"a={a}, b={b}"`, and will expand to

```
::fmt::format("a=" "{}" ", b=" "{}" "", a, b)
```

which is equivalent to

```
::fmt::format("a={}, b={}", a, b)
```

Looks good so far? It can even handle escape sequences (somehow)!

And here are the mentioned **major drawbacks**:

- Any sequence of whitespace characters is replaced with a single space.

  - Additionally, any leading and trailing whitespace, and any whitespace surrounding `ARG` is removed.
- Any macros in the string are expanded.
- The string can't contain unbalanced parentheses.
- `ARG(...)` can't appear inside of parentheses.

IMO, this makes it unusable for anything except debug output.

Possible workarounds include:

- Changing the syntax to one of:

  - `F("a = " ARG(a))` (I don't like how it looks)
  - `F("a = ", (a))` (looks decent, but requires Boost.Preprocessor or equivalent generated macros)
  - `F("a = ", ARG a)` (same)
  - `F("a = ", ()a)` (same)
- Adding a sub-macro (similar to `ARG`), let's say `STR("...")`, to include string literals verbatim. This will let you include any whitespace/parentheses/unexpanded macros/... you want.

  Example: `F(a = ARG(A))` gives you `a =42`. If you want a space after `=`, you do `F(a = STR(" ") ARG(A))`.

  The syntax is way too obscure, so implementing this is left as an exercise to the reader.
- ...

---

Bonus: with the right flags (or `#pragma`s), most compilers will let you include `$` in a macro name. It means you could use `$(expr)` instead of `ARG(expr)`, if you wanted to...

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no string interpolation in C++. And the only work in this area I've found is a "very very rough draft of a proposal" [Interpolated String Literals](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=forums&srcid=MTEwODAzNzI2MjM1OTc0MjE3MjkBMDg3NjY2MjM2ODE1ODYyNDk0NTgBSjZjZnVybm5CQUFKATAuMQFpc29jcHAub3JnAXYy&authuser=0) from [google](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/Yr9Zmrze2sg) back in 2015.

We just got the [formatting library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) in C++20 and even that is [does not appear to be yet implemented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) in any standard library implementation (as of July 2020). String interpolation would require **language support** and the standard committee is always more reluctant to change the language compared to changing the library.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to print a string with variables in it, you could always use the ancient [printf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm) function.

```
char my_name[] = "Michael";
int my_age = 107;
printf("Hello my name is %s. I am %d years old.", my_name, my_age);
```

[sprintf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) is a variant which allows you to save the output as a string (char array) and use it again, or send it to a serial port in the case of embedded systems.

I am far more familiar with C than python, so if I am missing something, please do explain.

Comment: Keep in mind that sprintf is actually unsafe - since it doesn't check the length of the destination buffer, you can overwrite memory that you shouldn't have access to. Better to use [std::snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) (even though it's technically still unsafe if you pass a larger buffer size than the buffer you're writing to)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method to use something like an "f-string" in c++ is the accepted answer to this other question [C++: how to get fprintf results as a std::string w/o sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738/c-how-to-get-fprintf-results-as-a-stdstring-w-o-sprintf#69911)